# Serialize multiple DataTables to JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, datatable

I want to serialize two `DataTables` to JSON, but I cannot do it. I looked at the examples, but I could not solve the problem. 
Help me please.

**My DataTables :**

```
    SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table1", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table2", con);

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    adp1.Fill(dt1);
    adp2.Fill(dt2);
```

**I want to get this result :**

```
var Json_Array = {
        "DataTable1":
            [
                {
                    "Id": "1",
                    "Name": "John"                       
                },
                {
                    "Id": "2",
                    "Name": "Mike"                        
                }
            ],
        "DataTable2":
            [
                {
                    "Mark": "Opel",
                    "Year": "1998"
                },
                {
                    "Mark": "Renault",
                    "Year": "2016"
                }
            ]
    };
```

Comment: use [newtonsoft.json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to convert datatable into JSON

Comment: Looking at your code it seems you want output as a single JSON object from two DataTables i.e. a DataSet to JSON

Comment: @haraman yes , how can I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your `DataTables` to an anonymous object and serialize that with [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
var data = new
{
    DataTable1 = dt1,
    DataTable2 = dt2
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ytKJnO

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved with this method

Comment: This is a simple solution and works even for datatables that have totally different structures.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Serializer to convert from DataTable to JSON - one such
Serializer is Newtonsoft.Json, download it from NuGet.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Code:

```
var oTable1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt1);
var oTable2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt2);
//Send back oTable1 and oTable2 to browser, choose your own way, e.g. 
//Response.Write(oTable1);
//Other way: Drag and drop two textbox(s) or two hiddenfield(s)
TextBox1.Text = oTable1;
TextBox2.Text = oTable2;
```

Or:

```
HiddenField1.Value = oTable1;
HiddenField2.Value = oTable2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make following class:

```
public class Test
{
   public DataTable[] DataTable1; 
   public DataTable[] DataTable2;
}
```

I wrote `DataTable[]` because in example JSON you got array on `DataTable1` and `DataTable2` fields

Initialize it with:

```
var objToSerialize = new Test(){DataTable1=new []{dt1}, DataTable2=new []{dt2}};
```

And then serialize it to json with Newtosoft.JSON with:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objToSerialize , Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved with this method

Comment: @SozdarCudi could mark my answer as response if it solve your problem? on stackoverflow you don't have to thanks: just vote up answer or mark it as response